# Error when keycloak.js is bundled with application but not otherwise

Tags: javascript, keycloak

I am having the following issue with keycloak.js,

**Scenario 1**:

In my application index.html (bundled in a JAR file and deployed in Jetty), I have the following code:

```
<script src="keycloak.js"></script>

<script>
  var keycloak = Keycloak({
    "realm": "master",
    "clientId": "client1",
    "auth-server-url": "http://<<keycloak-server-ip>>:<<port>>/auth",
    "public-count": true
    });

  keycloak.init({
      onLoad: 'login-required'
  }).success(function () {
     alert("login success");
  });

</script>
```

And I have the following client configuration in Keycloak server

```
Client Protocol - openid-connect
Access Type - public 
Standard Flow Enabled - ON
Implicit Flow Enabled - OFF
Direct Access Grants Enabled - ON
Authorization Enabled - OFF
Root URL -
Valid Redirect URIs - http://<<myapplicationIP>>:<<myapplicationPort>>/admin/*
Base URL - http://<<myapplicationIP>>:<<myapplicationPort>>/admin
Admin URL -
Web Origins -
```

With this configuration, the first time when I hit

`http://<myapplicationIP>:<myapplicationPort>/admin/` ,

I am getting redirected to

```
http://<<myapplicationIP>>:<<myapplicationPort>>/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect
/auth?client_id=client1&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F<<myapplicationIP>>%3A<<myapplicationPort>>%2Fadmin%2F&state=c524eb6c-9245-4f82-87e9-e767dd733b0d&nonce=760809b5-b2d5-4c3e-9d76-40cd43bdef0d&response_mode=fragment&response_type=code&scope=openid
```

and I get 404 which is expected since keycloak is trying to redirect to

```
http://<<myapplicationIP>>:<<myapplicationPort>>/realms/...
```

that does not exist in my application.

**Scenario 2**:

When I do the same thing as scenario 1 except the following, everything works as expected.

```
<script src="http://<<keycloakServerIP>>:<<keycloakServerPort>>/auth/js/keycloak.js"></script>
```

So, what is operationally different between bundling keycloak.js and loading it at run time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `url` instead of `auth-server-url` , answer is also available here : http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2017-July/011109.html